# Properties.Settings.Default.Reset() not reflected immediately -Needs Restart

Tags: c#, .net, user-input, properties.settings

On pressing a Button i reset the user stored settings like this

```
        Properties.Settings.Default.Reset();
```

But upon checking for stored data after the reset,the data still exists

```
outputdir = Properties.Settings.Default.OutputFolder;
            {
              if (outputdir.Length > 0)
              {
               //Data still exists 
              }
            }
```

The data seems to get  cleared only after program restart.How can i force delete user saved settings without restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below snippet:

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.Reset();
 Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```